# Stopping a previous search without using multithreading Java?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a webpage that allows the user to enter a search criteria. Upon submission of the search form using the get method, a controller class reads in the search parameters, sets them as request attributes, then directs back to the page, which then calls a java class that has database connections and sql queries. The question I have is this: when the user decides to perform a new search while the current search is still not finished, is there a way to terminate the current search on the server before starting the new one.

Comment: Is this question for Java or Javascript? The two are entirely different languages. I hope you don't have a Java applet on a web page with direct connections to a database...

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't gave many information here. Especially you didn't write how do you connects to database. If you are using **JDBC**, you can cancel executing query with [Statement.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel%28%29). Also you should hold information about current running query somewhere in session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `interrupt()` the thread that is doing the search and -admitted that the search Thread is doing some `Thread.sleep()` in between of performing the operations (eventually you should add those) - the thread will be interrupted by an `InterruptedException` that you should handle to break the search processing.

Still, you need to save the `Thread.currentThread()` somewhere (i.e. in the session) in order to retrieve a reference by the second one.

It's not trivial, and it's not very clean; since you need to put some interruption points in your search logic (i.e. the `Thread.sleep()` I mentioned before) and handle the `InterruptedException` properly.

For sure, the easier way is to ignore that the previous thread is still running and perform a new search.